# "uninitialized value" error when wrapping tensorflow code into a python function

Tags: python, tensorflow

The error is "Attempting to use uninitialized value state_variable". But I think this code should be initializing that value.

Here is my code, thank you:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def index():
    state = tf.Variable(0, name="state_variable")
    new_value = tf.add(state, tf.constant(1))
    update = tf.assign(state, new_value)
    return update

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        init_op = tf.group(tf.local_variables_initializer(),
                           tf.global_variables_initializer())
        op = index()
        sess.run(init_op)
        for _ in range(4):
            print(sess.run(op))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the `op = index()` line *before* the line that defines `init_op` using `tf.group`. Currently when you call `tf.group`, `tf.Variable(0, name="state_variable")` has not yet been called, so `tf.group` doesn't know to put its initialization into `init_op`. The following version runs fine on my machine:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def index():
    state = tf.Variable(0, name="state_variable")
    new_value = tf.add(state, tf.constant(1))
    update = tf.assign(state, new_value)
    return update

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        op = index()
        init_op = tf.group(tf.local_variables_initializer(),
                           tf.global_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(init_op)
        for _ in range(4):
            print(sess.run(op))
```